# Prove $\lvert a − b\rvert \le \lvert a − c\rvert + \lvert c − d\rvert + \lvert d − b\rvert$ for all $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Prove $\lvert a − b\rvert \le \lvert a − c\rvert + \lvert c − d\rvert + \lvert d − b\rvert$ for all $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$.

I am unsure how to start this problem but I think it involved the triangle inequality in some way.

Comment: What is $(a-c)+(c-d)+(d-b)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do many legal things in mathematics like adding and subtracting the same quantity to a given expression

so if a have $a-b$ I can write it as

$a-b= a-c+c-d+d-b$

and of course the absolute values are also equal. I mean

$|a-b|= |a-c+c-d+d-b|\quad (*)$

and we know the triangle inequality

$|x+y|\le |x|+|y|$

therefore from $(*)$ we can conclude that

$|a-b|= |(a-c)+(c-d)+(d-b)|\le |a-c|+|c-d|+|d-b|$

Hope this can help

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you may use the triangle inequality, i.e. $|x+y|\leq |x|+ |y|$.
Note that
\begin{align*}
|a − b|&=|(a-c)+(c-b)|\leq  |a − c| + |c − b|=|a − c| + |(c-d)+(d− b)|\\ 
&\leq   |a − c| + |c − d| + |d − b|.
\end{align*}